# When importing function, additional instructions come attached

Tags: function, python-3.x, import

I have a .py file containing a function:

```
import random

def random_m(a):

b = [[0 for _ in range(a)] for _ in range(a)]
for i in range(a):
    for j in range(a):
        b[i][j] = random.randint(100,999)
    print('{}'.format(b[i],[j]))

n = int(input("Enter dimension of matrix: "))
random_m(n)
```

Now I want to use this function in another .py file. 
I write:

```
from file1.py import random_m 
random_m(10)
```

When executing the file, it keeps asking me to enter the dimension of matrix. Why? That instruction is not included in the function's body. I already inserted the argument '10'.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Python first evaluate all the code of the file and then the function is pushed in your namespace

Comment: The `input` function is used at the module's level. When you import that module, everything at the module level is evaluated. If you want to avoid that, you could use the `if __name__ == '__main__': <whatever>` construct in the module.

Comment: Even if you only import `random_m`, Python has to initialize the whole module, because `random_m` might depend on other module contents.

Answer (score 0):

```
def random_m(a):
  b = [[0 for _ in range(a)] for _ in range(a)]
  for i in range(a):
    for j in range(a):
      b[i][j] = random.randint(100,999)
    print('{}'.format(b[i],[j]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  n = int(input("Enter dimension of matrix: "))
  print(random_m(n))
```

This will execute the input function (and everything under `if __name__ == '__main__':`) only when the module is not imported (for example, when you double click it in windows )